# error at Data Flow Task the data type DT_WSRT and DT_I4 are incompatibale

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I use SQL Server 2012 and SSIS.

I create a connection from flat file .

My file like this :

[image]

and then i create a integration project and then i create data flow and then i drag and drop one conditional split.

[image]

and then i set this condition :

[image]

and when i press ok button i get this error :

[image]

i think that i most change type of salary ?!?

how i can fix it?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289640/how-to-import-a-fixed-width-flat-file-into-database-using-ssis/10293301#10293301) has a lot of good info for *flat file* sources

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you most convert salary field with one of this two way :

1 : When you create connection you can change datatype of columns .

2 : In conditional split you can use a type cast like this :

```
(type cast)(Your Field)
```

And for your question you can use this `(DT_I4)Salary > 20000` in Condition Column.

Answer (score 1):

In `Flat file source` you can specify what is the type of read data - probably it is still set to `string(50)` and that's why you can't compare string vs integer value.

Another easy way out is to cast your string variable to integer in Condition:
`(DT_I4)Salary > 20000`