# Import Flat file to SQL - No error thrown after adding a character

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis, etl, flat-file

I am working on a package that loads data from a text file onto a table on SQL server.

The text file has data in the below format

[image]

I am including the flat file connection manager here -

[image]

I have created a test table

[image]

executed the package and moved data onto the table.

[image]

And, then edited one of the column to include more characters (included s in the second column)

[image]

and instead of the package erroring out..it ran successfully and moved the extra characters to the next column.

[image]

Can someone help me out here ?

Comment: Can you show the tasks that actually consume the text file and insert into the table?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: @digital.aaron the situation is clear, he is reading the Flat file Source as a fixed width columns

Comment: @tanu this is what i mentioned in my question you are using "Ragged right" flat file source which is the same as fixed width. check my answer update for more info

Comment: @Hadi The flat file source screenshot wasn't included in the original version of the question.

Comment: @digital.aaron sorry i missed that.

Comment: @Hadi - is there any work around...where it can throw error in such case

Comment: and @digital.aaron - is there any work around...where it can throw error in such case

Comment: The only way I know would be to use a delimited format for your flat file. Why do you want the task to fail in this case?

Comment: @tanu you have to use delimited format, and read each row as one column `(DT_WSR(4000))` and check if the length is > 21 then throw an error else split the column using derived columns transformation (`SUBSTRING` function)

Comment: @digital.aaron - so, the source file is a text file and destination is a table on sql server. I  just want it to fail whenever it comes in a format that is not supposed to...does it make sense ?

Comment: @Hadi - sure. I'll def try it out. I am not sure how it works but I am going to try

Comment: @Hadi - can you explain about it in much more detail. I am not really sure how this can be done on derived column transformation. Thank you

Comment: @tanu i edited my answer 2 days ago, did yoy try my suggestions?

Comment: @Hadi - I tried but not really sure about how to do it. i'll try again and let you know if it works. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @Tanu is the problem solved?

Comment: @hadi - I didn’t know how to work around that

Comment: @Tanu it is a step-by-step workaround !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Why package is not throwing an exception?

This is normal, you are reading the Flat file Source as a fixed width columns, (Fixed width or Ragged right) with the following specifications.

> "Ragged Right", which is exactly the same as "Fixed Width", except that it gives you the option to insert a linefeed character (or CRLF, etc.) at the end of each line of data.

*(You can check the Flat File connection manager to see the specifications)*

**Initial State**

*Data:*

```
0001aijn fkds jmcl wuj
```

*Specifications and Result :*

```
Col001: From 0 -> 3      '0001'
Col002: From 4 -> 7      'aijn'
Col003: From 8 -> 11     ' fkd'
Col004: From 12 -> 13    's '
Col005: From 14 -> 18    'jmcl '
Col006: From 19 -> end   'wuj'
```

**Second State**

*So when you added a `S` character the data looks like:*

```
0001aijns fkds jmcl wuj
```

*Specifications and Result :*

```
Col001: From 0 -> 3      '0001'
Col002: From 4 -> 7      'aijn'
Col003: From 8 -> 11     's fk'
Col004: From 12 -> 13    'ds'
Col005: From 14 -> 18    ' jmcl'
Col006: From 19 -> end   ' wuj'
```

**For more informations:**

- [How to import a fixed width flat file into database using SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289640/how-to-import-a-fixed-width-flat-file-into-database-using-ssis)
- [SSIS Flat File Export - "Fixed Width" vs "Ragged Right"](https://weblogs.asp.net/guystarbuck/ssis-flat-file-export-quot-fixed-width-quot-vs-quot-ragged-right-quot)

---

## Is there any work around...where it can throw error in such case?

1. In the Flat File Connection manager use the `Delimited Format`
2. Go To the Advanced Tab, Delete all Columns Except one column
3. Change the Datatype to `DT_WSTR` and the length to `4000`
4. In  the Data Flow Task add a Flat File Source, Conditional Split, Script Component, Derived Column Transformation, OLEDB Destination as Shown in the image below

[image]

5. Use the Conditional Split to filter rows based on the length of the column:

   ```
   LEN([Column0]) == 22
   ```

[image]

6. In the Script Component write the Following Code *(used to raise error if there is a row of length > 22)*:

   ```
   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

       Throw New Exception("Length constraint violated")

   End Sub
   ```
7. Specify the following Derived Columns

[image]

8. Map the result to the `OLEDB Destination`

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any difference in the behaviour of the two cases. Both times it is reading 4 characters from the input file and putting them in column 1, reading the next 4 characters into column 2, the next four characters into column 3, then 2 characters into column 4, 5 characters into column 5, and finally 4 characters (if there are that many left) into column 6. Note that it is counting the spaces as characters, so in the first run it is including the space between `aijn` and `fkds` at the beginning of the entry in column 3, whereas in the second run the extra `s` is now the first character in column 3 and the space becomes the second character.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your SSIS package to accommodate added length.

For this, right click on your target Destination - Show advanced editor:
[image]

Check and fix the length of the internal column:

[image]

And lastly check the length of external column:

[image]

Hope this help :)