# Derive column does not substring desired columns from row input

Tags: ssis, derived-column

My question is about using "Derived Column Transformation".

**Situation:**

A row already retrieved from flat file successfully. I am trying to derive multiple columns by using "Derived Column" and `substring` function. There are as many as 36 columns that I need to derive from the given string. 
Issue occurs when after deriving first 3 columns from the row, `substring()` somehow cannot read row or derive further columns.

**Input Row:** (Total length of each row would be 400 characters)

ANICHOLLS, JASON, ROBERT                             19700613136643-590      AB5731 MAIDSTONE CRES NE                          CALGARY                 T2A4C3113  GAST  A00405860F       DRUPDRUMHELLER          TSA131(1)(G)           20030520   OPERATE OVERWEIGHT VEH  2007061801055STRSTRATHMORE                    00005750{BBB235    AB0020070625                                         200707191005209

**Effort to Derive column:**
[image]
[image: trying to see output while debugging]

Am I trying wrong syntax here?

Comment: If you know your column widths, you should change your flat file connection to a fixed-width format and scrap trying to parse out the columns yourself. Use the tools to make your work easier, not more complicated.

Comment: I agree with @digital.aaron Use the fixed width importer. It will also let you choose the correct data types.  However, you should be able to do exactly what you are attempting without any issues. I've done what you are doing only when there are multiple row types. Like Header and details in the same file.

Comment: I have already used fixed-width format and so it shows me correct number of rows as well while deriving columns from them. @digital.aaron, Can you further elaborate or show reference which tools could I use for easy derivation?

Comment: @Binoy here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289640/how-to-import-a-fixed-width-flat-file-into-database-using-ssis

Comment: @KeithL, +1. your response helped. Just for knowledge, what if the column width is known but values may or may not appear in file to derive particular column!

Comment: fixed width files typically are whitespace (or zero for numeric) padded. if you have inconstant widths then you have to conditionally split and have a split like you currently started you project with or you can save the split files and use the GUI tool on each file type in it's own data flow..

Comment: @Binoy, by "tools" i was referring to the built-in functionality of BIDS/SSDT. In software development in general, and SSIS in particular, there are often several completely different approaches to solving a problem. Yes, you can build your own fixed-width file parser in SSIS, or you can use the one that comes standard. Both can theoretically solve the problem, but one takes much less effort to implement.