# Microsoft SSIS - Load a flat file (.csv) with multiple commas (,) and no double quotations (") - into a SQL Server table

Tags: csv, ssis, etl, flat-file, quotations

I have a situation in which our client has given a flat file (`.csv`) to be loaded into a SQL Server table using SSIS.

This huge raw `.csv` file (with about 400,000 records) does not have a proper csv format - particularly it does not have the double quotation ("), either in the column name header or in the row data. Please see an example below:

```
ColumnName 1, ColumnName 2, ColumnName 3,....

Z ,  342343242424  , 10.83  ,  000001001765  , 2018-12-03 , 2018-12-03 ,  ABCD  ,  **XYZ,**  ,  CA ,  001  ,  00  , ?
```

(This is an instance of a data row, with the column header names as Column 1, Column 2,...There is no double quotation(") at all in this file with extension .csv)

I am using Visual Studio 2017 to work in SSIS.

As you can see the data value **XYZ,**    is desired as **XYZ,** in a single cell; instead I see XYZ in one cell and a blank in the adjacent cell to the right. (I am currently de-bugging using a Data Viewer.)

Every cell gets shifted one place to the right side. In the last column on the right side, I get this:   **00  , ?**  in one cell.

In the SSIS Flat File Connection Manager Editor - General page, I have set the following properties:

```
Format: Delimited
Text Qualifier:    none
Header row delimiter:  {CR}{LF}
```

I do not have an idea on how to load this sort of an improperly formatted `.csv` file (without double quotations(")).

Is there a way I can load properly ? May be changing the file to a text file or something.

I have been told that these are **Cobol (Mainframe)** files with fixed specific width for each column.

There is also a specific width for each filler (i.e. blank space (including comma) between adjacent values). I have been given a specification document with information such as this below:

```
Field Name           Start          Width
-----------------------------------------    
ColumnName1             1            26
FILLER                  27            5
ColumnName2             32           19
FILLER                  51            5
ColumnName3             56           21
FILLER                  77            5
.
.
.
.
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: SSIS supports fixed with CSVs as far as I remember. Try checking this question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289640/how-to-import-a-fixed-width-flat-file-into-database-using-ssis I think it's exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: In the SSIS Flat File Connection Manager Editor - General page, when I choose the following :

Format: Fixed Width,

I am not seeing all the columns from the source .csv file.
I am seeing just one column called Column0 in the Advanced tab.

In the Columns tab, even after adjusting the row width, I see only one column.

Am I doing something wrong  to use the fixed width property ?

Comment: You probably have to declare these columns yourself, together with their lengths.

Comment: OK, will get back with the result on Monday. Thanks Evaldas.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas      Is there a way to add the columns manually either in the Flat File connection manager or the Flat File source in the SSIS Data Flow ? I think SSIS does the sensing of columns automatically, right ? (I am yet to try what you have mentioned from my end, but just wanted to get it clear whether you have any specific strategy to do this). I will re-start the work on Monday. But feel free to comment if you have something in mind

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas    In SSRS, I know we can manually add columns that the dataset columns does not spot automatically.

Comment: I'll be able to check that myself next year chap. Is sample data in your question correct?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas The data sample is correct. But **XYZ,**   is actually   XYZ followed by a comma on its own, not any astrix symbol. Somehow the editing is not good in stackoverflow, I tried to use Bold.  You can have a look here too:                   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0dae6f87-c9d9-4f3f-88f2-cba3e54b4f0f/microsoft-ssis-load-a-flat-file-csv-with-multiple-commas-and-no-double-quotations?forum=sqlintegrationservices&prof=required

Comment: I have posted the solution myself in the social msdn link above